# ProcessBuilder and stdin/stdout of its child processes

Tags: java, bash

I currently create a ProcessBuilder passing a command "bash -c [bashCommandString]".  The bashCommandString in turn runs "bash -c [anotherCommandString]".

My code calls Process.getInputStream and getOutputStream to get stdout and stdin of the process started through the ProcessBuilder.

In this case,

1) will the stdin and stdout of script run in [anotherCommandString] be retrievable with Process.getInputStream and getOutputStream?

2) will IO performance of stdin and stdout be affected by this nesting of script executions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try it for yourself, since it's pretty easy to implement. If you are having issues implementing something, you should return with the code, and we will be glad to help you.

Comment: I tried it, and Process.getInputStream and getOutputStream are able to retrieve stdout and stdin.  But I would like to understand why and whether performance is worse due to the nesting of script execution. Thank you.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in Linux, a child process inherits the parent's stdin and stdout. The first bash script is a child of your Java process, and the second bash script is a child of the first bash script. Not sure about performance - probably a negligible difference, but as usual, if you really need to know, you need to profile it.